# Creating a link to a named range that is found using a formula and is specific to that sheet

Tags: hyperlink, named-ranges

I have a google worksheet that I am creating to use with a sale team.
I have a master sheet which has mutliple tabs, one being the dashboard and one being training.

On the dashboard, I have a formula created to let the sales person know what training they need to do next based on where they are in their progress. I have figured out to automatically create that text on the dashboard to hyperlink to the training tab and to the right named range in the training tab based on a formula.

The issue is when we create a copy of the worksheet, the URL is for the Master sheet, not for the new sheet.

Example: I have a MASTERSALESPROGRESS worksheet.

The Dashboard tab shows sales progress and what training is next.
I am using this formula to find the right training and to create the link to the cells which explain what to do in that training: =HYPERLINK(VLOOKUP(AC3,$AC$5:$AF$23,2,0),AC3) and this returns the named range.
On the dashboard, I link to this result and it works perfect.

Now we Make a Copy for Lisa, a new sales person.
Her training links all link to the MASTERSALESPROGRESS and not to her sheet.

Help! I can import the URL of her indiviudal sheet and try to add a named range to the end or the URL, but that doesn't seem to be working for me, especially if the link we notate has the ...?usp=sharing at the end of it.

I know there has to be a way.